# <lightning:input type=“toggle”> how to set the label above the input component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightninginput

I am using `lightning:input type=“toggle”`,

By default the label is displayed to the left of the component:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<lightning:input type="toggle"
                 label="My Label: "
                 name="toggle"
                 checked="{!v.record.myCheckbox__c}"/>
```

I want the label to be displayed above the toggle button, but cannot find a way to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, SLDS doesn't have a "toggle with label above" out of the box, so lightning:input doesn't really have a feature like this, either. However, you can simulate it with a few SLDS bits:

```
<div class="slds-form slds-form_stacked">
    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="toggle">My Label</label>
        <lightning:input type="toggle"
                         label=""
                         variant="label-hidden"
                         name="toggle"
                         /> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Otherwise, you might want to stick with writing your own [custom toggle component using slds](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/checkbox-toggle/), instead, but customize it to use a stacked label.

Comment: I have used your solution and added the attribute `variant="label-hidden"` this way the label is hidden and it looks perfect

Comment: @ItaiShmida Ah. I missed something, too. We both learned something today!

Comment: how to change label color

Comment: @SagarRaut Comments are not for new questions, and I'm really not sure what *specifically* you're asking for. Please ask a new question, include all pertinent details, and we'll be glad to help you. You can read more about [ask] a good question.